# Retrieving the size of a file stored in S3

Tags: scrapy

My spiders use filespipeline to save files to an S3 bucket.  I have overridden `filespipeline.file_path` to give each S3 blob a nice Key, and my Item class has a field called `binary_size`, into which I would like to insert the size of the downloaded/uploaded file.

To achieve this I overrode `filespipeline.item_completed`, in which I lookup the item on the S3 bucket (deriving the same item Key as decided in `file_path`), get it's size, then set it on and return the item. It seems very simple!

It appears however that during execution of `item_completed`, the S3 bucket does not yet contain the item. My code fails with a simple traceback "Key does not exist".

Is there a place that I can hook in to modify the item at some time when I can be sure that the blob will exist in S3?

Any clues, however faint or spare, will be appreciated!  It's all working so nicely, I don't want to have to do the S3 stuff manually.